# What is the way to reduce clutter in Redux actions?

Tags: javascript, redux

The common pattern to declare actions in Redux is to assign constant to a string.

```
const ACTION = 'ACTION';
```

But in a real world, this approach makes the actions part of your app bloated. It’s hard to add and write such low-level stuff. I saw and wrote by myself a lot of that ridiculous `constants.js`s that contains only strings bounded to consts. Well, it makes me feel old school and COBOLish, but that’s the only benefits of this approach to me.

I believe, it’s not a good pattern for real life applications.

What is your way to declare and reuse actions?

And why the Redux lib was designed so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What *specifically* isn't a good pattern? Constants? Strings?

Nothing mandates action types *must* be strings–that's [a convention](https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action#user-content-type). Types can be symbols, objects, or anything else that can be used to make decisions in the code.

[FSAs are explicitly intended to be human-friendly](https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action), and humans are good at reading text.

Check out the [Reducing Boilerplate](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html) section, e.g., any of the [action](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-actions) [creator](https://github.com/grigory-leonenko/redux-easy-actions) [libraries](https://github.com/pauldijou/redux-act).

Comment: > What specifically isn't a good pattern? Constants? Strings?

No, writing a of boilerplate stuff in general, both contsants and action creators.

Comment: Thanks for links you provided

Comment: That said, the `type` field _should_ be serializable in order to ensure that time-travel debugging works properly, and strings work best because they are both serializable and readable.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Actions.html#actions-string-constants for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the redux-ducks proposal to make your actions/reducers more modular and maintainable. No more constants.js files full of action types.

https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux

As for reusing actions, you could use redux thunk/saga to create chains of actions. this way you can reuse actions multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Well Personally even I was really irritated by declaring a constants file. It was bloating my project and the bundle size kept on increasing.

I would say if you have a reducer doing same work for different actions  you should definitely take a look at [higher order reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html). The link is from redux docs itself.

I will try to explain this with the help of following code.

Consider you have constants file in which I do

```
export default RECEIVE_DICT_2 = 'RECEIVE_DICT_2'
export default RECEIVE_DICT_1 = 'RECEIVE_DICT_1'
```

Consider you have a reducers

***First Reducer***

```
const state = {
   dict : {},
}

function firstReducer(state = state,action){
  switch(action.type){

    case 'RECEIVE_DICT_1':
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        dict : action.dict
     })
 }
```

***Second Reducer***

```
const state = {
   dict : {},
}
function secondReducer(state = state,action){
  switch(action.type){

    case 'RECEIVE_DICT_2': 
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        dict : action.dict
     })
 }
```

Now if you see both the reducers do exactly same the thing but while dispatching actions you need to specify each keys since we specified this in constants.

So you actions would be like

```
firstAction(dict){
return {
   action:'RECEIVE_DICT_1',
   dict
  }
}

secondAction(dict){
return {
   action:'RECEIVE_DICT_2',
   dict
  }
}
```

Clearly this is too much code bloat. So here we can use higher order reducers and just throw away that constants file.

Now your reducer would something like this

```
export default function parentReducer(code){
 return function commons(state = state,action){
  switch(action.type){
    case `RECEIVE_DICT_${code}`:
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        dict : action.dict
      })
    }
  }
 }
```

I hope you get the picture. You can read more about this in the link I shared above.

Comment: Great, your idea with ES2015 string templates can be helpful in some cases.